# Error in make file in eclipse

Tags: makefile, eclipse-cdt

I tried to build my project in eclipse mars using CDT editor it shows error in makefile. I am very new to handle makefile, I have attached 2 images what I saw in project explorer.

[image: makefile error]

When I try to build my project it shows error

> 1.mingw32-make.exe: *** [build/driver] Error 1
>
> 2.recipe for target 'build/driver' failed Makefile

Need help to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you show what is the BUILD_DIR variable ? The Q variable ? And can you show the output on console view ? Thx.

Comment: @LaurentH. I got resolved this issue. I gave the wrong build command after giving the correct build path and build command project compiled successfully Thanks